# How to add conditional price mark up in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been looking for this for a long time and can't seem to find an answer
I want to add mark up to my products based on their current price
e.g Products b/w £0-49 I want to £5
49-100 £10 and so on
But i want the markup to be part of the price displayed on shop and product page. (As In I don't want customer to see that I have added a markup)
any help will be appreciated. 
Cheers

Comment: Why don't you do that in SQL? You can easily apply a % markup or conditional markup to your products using a SQL query. Or alternatively on the CSV before upload

Comment: The stock file comes from supplier and gets synced everyday using wpallimport. They do have an option for mark up but it's same markup across the board on all products

Comment: So edit it once the products are in the db either by using a sql query directly or write your own tool to do it automatically after import

Comment: Possibly [dynamic pricing](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter all the prices via `woocommerce_get_price`. Assuming that you want to add £5 for every £50 you could do something like:

```
function so_32352745_filter_price( $price ){
    $factor = floor( $price / 50 );
    $price = $price + $factor * 5;
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'so_32352745_filter_price' );
```